# Issue with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with Office 2010 with Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop

I am working on a requirement to read the word document and populate data into Datatable or excel sheet using C# code.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Office 2016 in my machine. In my solution I have added the references  Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library to work with word documents. But when i deployed the solution production server Code is not working and I ma getting the error like

"System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))."

In Production we are using Office 2010. I think it is raising the issue because of compatibility issues between 2010 and 2016 references

Is this possible to add office 2010 reference from the system in which office 2016 is installed from visual studio 2015?

Could you please someone let me know how to fix this issue

Comment: @Mikael that's a different error. The OP's error is `Library not registered` which means Word either isn't installed or the application asks for the wrong version

Comment: `production server` ? Word isn't supposed to run on a server, definitely not on *Web* servers as it requires a license for *every* browser user. Never mind that each operation would require a separate Word instance, quickly exhausting the server's RAM.

Comment: As for the version - your code is explicitly asking for Word 2016 when only Word 2010 is installed. 6 years is long enough to introduce new APIs and remove obsolete ones. If you intend to use an unlicensed old version of Word 1) don't 2) Replace the Word 16.0 object library with one that supports the Word version you want to use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : the actual issue is the code was implemented on Visual Studio 2015 in the system in which of 2016 was installed. So when i am  adding the reference Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library as per the availability. But actually the code has to run on the system in which office 2010 was installed.  is there any possibility that we can add word reference ( any version ) that can be compatible with 2010 t0 2016 office versions. if yes how can we add them